# Notifying an item changed inside a nested adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I have one `ParentAdapter` that has multiple view holders and each view holder has its own RecyclerView and an adapter.

I am facing a problem when I need to notify an item of a child adapter is changed. I passed the position of the changed child view holder to the parent and I can use `notifyItemChanged(position)` but the whole child adapter is recreated.

What I need is to be able to notify a child item and keep the state of the child recyclerview as it is.

**Here's the code of the Parent Adapter:**

```
class ParentAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    
    private var items = listOf<ParentItem>()

    companion object {
        const val CHILD_ONE = 1
        const val CHILD_TWO = 2
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        context = parent.context
        
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        return when(viewType) {
            CHILD_ONE -> {
                ChildOneViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_one, parent, false))
            }
            CHILD_TWO -> {
                ChildTwoViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_two, parent, false))
            }
            else -> {
                BlankItemViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, parent, false))
            }
        }
    }

    fun update(items: List<Section>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        
        val item = items[position]
        
        return when(item.type) {
            1 -> CHILD_ONE
            2 -> CHILD_TWO
            else -> -1
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder.itemViewType) {
            CHILD_ONE -> {
                val section = items[position]
                
                val childOneAdapter = ChildOneAdapter(this)

                if(!section.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    holder.rvChildOne.apply {
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                        adapter = childOneAdapter
                        isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
                    }

                    childOneAdapter.update(section.items)
                }
            }

            CHILD_TWO -> {
                val section = items[position]

                val childTwoAdapter = ChildTwoAdapter(this)

                if(!section.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    holder.rvChildTwo.apply {
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                        adapter = childTwoAdapter
                        isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
                    }

                    childTwoAdapter.update(section.items)
                }
            }
            else ->
                initBlankSection(holder as BlankItemViewHolder, position)
        }
    }

    private fun initBlankSection(holder: BlankItemViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    private class ChildOneViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val rvChildOne: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_child_one)
    }

    private class ChildTwoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val rvChildTwo: RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_child_two)
    }

    private class BlankItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sens ... same would happen if you scroll child item out of view and bring it back - that's how recylerview works) unless you are using RecyclerView without recycling ability but then you can use somethign different (like simple ScrollView with generated items)

Comment: I mentioned the approach that failed for me

Comment: It's up to item to keep the state ... so you can recreate its visiual state when is needed ... fx you can store in parent item first visible item postion and when adapter of child is recreated scroll it there

Comment: That's not the issue @Selvin I need to notify a child adapter with changes